# Where can i find the printed information generated in the cpp files of NS2 library in which I added some cout() functions to print some information?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ns2, ns-3

I'm using ns2 in linux to do some network experiments.  I added some print lines in some of the cpp files of the ns library(through the function cout()). But when I execute the TCL scripts, I can't see the printed information on the screen. So where can i find the printed information generated in the cpp files?

Comment: You are looking at one of three options here: 1) you didn't recompile the libraries, 2) your scripts aren't *using* the recompiled libraries, 3) standard output was redirected elsewhere. I'd suggest writing to a file (given with full path) instead of `cout` to rule out 3).

Comment: Thank you for the reply and I really appreciate it. The first two reasons can be ruled out, as I did recompile the libraries and used them. I think it's a matter of redirection, as you mentioned in 3). I will try using full path now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan ,  Hi.

Ns2 is an otcl / tcl application.
The "functions" must also be compiled into ns-2.3x/tcl/lib/{ files.tcl }.

Example "print a message" is the default HELLO :

cd ns-2.3x/tcl/lib/ && 
grep -in hello ns-lib.tcl

860: self at 0.0 "$ragent start" ;# start BEACON/HELLO Messages

867: self at 0.0 "$ragent start" ;# start BEACON/HELLO Messages

891: self at 0.0 "$ragent start" ;# start BEACON/HELLO Messages

You can also check where HELLO is present in files.cc :
cd ns-2.3x/ &&
grep -Rin hello *

-